# Why am I getting so many .pdb files?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-c++

I'm using MSVC 2013 compiler, CDB debugger, and Qt Creator/qmake under Windows 7.  I just discovered that the build directory for one of my projects is a whopping 16 *gigabytes*.  The culprit is a sub-directory named "srv" which contains various .pdb files.  The curious part is that there are pdb files for all kinds of system libraries like commctl32, ntdll, user32, etc.  Do I really need to generate pdb's for these system files, or is this some setting that I can turn off, or is it a bug?  I don't plan to debug user32.dll, so I can't see any reason to have debug information generated for it.

Comment: Sounds like a cache directory for files pulled form the symbol server when debugging. The symbols are used to generate stack traces even if you don't directly debug those modules.  I'm not too familiar with QtCreator, but there's probably a setting so that you can cache these files in a single global location so that all your QtCreator projects will use the same cache instead of having separate instances.  If it is a cache, you can remove it but the debugger will likely pull them down again over the internet as needed.

Comment: "I don't plan to debug user32.dll" No, but you will plan on knowing what user32 function your program crashed in, right? That's what these files are for. Debugging without them is no fun. Modern development needs ample disk space - get used to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pdb files for commctl32, ntdll, user32 are not generated (as those libraries are not compiled by you). Those are automatically downloaded when you debug applications for resolving the memory addresses into function names (i.e., preparing a readable stack trace).

You can configure this in VS2013 settings, Debugging, Symbols. There you can disable automatic downloading and/or change the folder where to put the files. Suppose this can also be disabled/configured for other debuggers.

The "symbol cache" grows: whenever you install windows updates, new libraries might get deployed to your computer and in your next debugging sessions new symbols are downloaded. If you have a fast internet connection, it's no problem to empty the cache.